# Как убрать текст: Hey there! Now that a command has been ran, you should be able to get your Active Developer badge on?

Tags: python, discord, disnake

Код:

```py
from disnake.ext import commands

class Ping(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Pong!")

    @commands.slash_command()
    async def pong(self, interaction):
        await interaction.respone.send_message("Pong!")


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Ping(bot))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ожидал ответ -> "Pong!".

Comment: Судя по сообщению, он говорит о том что вы можете получить метку "Активный Разработчик" (Active Developer badge), и предлагает перейти по ссылке чтобы это сделать. Метка присваивается примерно через 24 часа после подачи, и как вы ее получите это сообщение больше не будет появляться

Comment: Я это прекрасно знаю, но данный значок у меня уже 3 месяца. (: Возможно это из-за частого забрасывания разработки дискорд-бота на месяц и более.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос можно закрыть. Я исправил этот баг с помощью замены своего старого бота на нового.
P/s ещё в коде содержится ошибка.
**Исправление в низу.**

```
 @commands.slash_command()
 async def ping(self, interaction: disnake.CommandInter):
     await interaction.response.send_message(f"Pong!")
```